# Ember js/Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember application running with hadlebars. I have several ember templates in my HTML page, but I ran into a slight dilemma - I can't escape an HTML code within script tag. I am looking to insert a non-working raw HTML into script tag for illustrative purposes. Will it be of help by using .hbs file method? I would prefer not to use .hbs method.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="name">
<html>
<head>
so on....
</head>
</html>
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't escape an HTML code"? Why do you need to escape it? Like you actually want to show HTML code in the document instead of putting HTML into the document?

Comment: yes. I am attempting to display the non-working HTML code on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this exactly the same way you would do it in normal HTML: escape the HTML entities:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="name">
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
so on....
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</script>
```

Comment: I have lines and lines of HTML code. I need a "bulk" escape tag.

Comment: There isn't one. The best you can do is to store the HTML in a string variable inside of your Javascript, place it on your template's controller, then insert the value using `{{value}}` and rely on the Handlebars runtime to escape it for you.